# Are Java's CDI events clustered in WildFly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi

I'm using `javax.enterprise.event.Event` interface widely on my web applications, where I fire and observe many events.

It works like a charme, unless when I deploy the applications on a clustered environment (WildFly 10.1) where the events are observed only on the node where the event is fired.

The WildFly profile of the server group used by the nodes is "full-ha" and all the applications are `<distributable />` on their web.xml descriptor, and SFSB are correctly clustered over all the nodes.

So I have a couple of questions.

1. Are CDI events supposed to work on a clustered environment? I can't find any reference to this.
2. If yes, how can I make them work, i.e. firing an event and observing it in every node? If not, how can I workaround this in WildFly?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are sailing undefined waters - that's why you found no reference.

It seems *not to work in Wildfly ATM* but it would be an interesting addition - feel free to create [JIRA issue for Weld](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

In Paraya, this seems to work already, but there are limitations - read up in their [docs](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/extended-documentation/cdi-events.html) if you wish to.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Payara's implementation. I've created https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9272 to keep track on this.